# How to access json data with volley?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-volley

I have following JSON data. How to get values of latitudes and longitudes from this data (inside "center" array which is inside "features" array)

Link to json data-

```
    https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/Los%20Angeles.json?access_token=REDACTED&limit=1
```

Comment: for a security issue, remove your api key from the question

Answer (score 0):

To use Volley, you need to add this dependency to your module's build.gradle file

> implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'

Since you are expecting json object in the response, use com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest:

```
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.GET,
            URL, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                    //Parse the reponse for the center object
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Create POJO model and parse json response and put into model class.

You can create POJO model with this [link](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/)